# Measuring the divergence in centrality statistics for similar networks?

Tags: similarities, networks, divergence

I want to measure the similarity/divergence between the centrality of nodes in two publicly available word association networks.

In my analysis, we have a long list of nodes - 12,000 or so - and then we have (centrality measures) in-degree, betweenness, and PageRank data for (a) all of these nodes in Network A, and (b) only some of those nodes in Network B. Regarding only the nodes which have data available in both networks, I want to find out the divergence in the centrality of the nodes for each of the centrality measures.

I have considered using KL divergence, but I think that this is designed to be used for a probability distribution, so I'm not sure that it would work with my centrality measures.

I also wondered if simple correlation would be appropriate?

Extra points for suggesting an R package which can run your suggested method!